# Assigning a type to generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to simplify my generic functions by assigning a common type to them if it's possible.

Firstly, I created a Reducer type:

```
type Reducer<C, B, R> = (computed: C) => (body: B) => R;
```

And here are my functions that actually implements Reducer but I can't find the way to assign this type to these functions:

```
const ignore = <C>(computed: C) => <B>(body: B): B => body;
const assign = <C>(computed: C) => <B>(body: B): C => computed;
const modify = <C>(computed: C) => <B>(body: B): B & C => Object.assign(body, computed);
```

I wonder if there is a way to assign the Reducer type to them, and/or simplify these expressions by taking out a common factor to keep it away from repetition?

Comment: In order to do this you would need "higher-kinded types" which are not supported by Typescript.  Your current `Reducer` can only take a predefined type for `C` and `B`, but your functions can take a `C` and `B` which varies for each function call.  You would need to define the `R` as some operation of a generic `B` and `C`: "choose B", "choose C", or "combine them".  But those operations would be higher-kinded types which don't exist.